# Data is not loading for grid from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I am trying to create a fidlle where data will load from json. But I don't know why data is not loading.

Here is my fiddle  [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25od)

Here is my data store code

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'Ajax_Store',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'emp.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty:"Emp"
        }
    },
    autoLoad : true,
    fields: ['E_ID','E_FName','E_LName','E_Place']
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have enabled "dynamic data" but not returned anything from the function body:

[image]

If you disable dynamic data, you will find that JSON does only use double quotes. Corrected JSON file:

```
{"Emp" : [{
   "E_ID": 125,
   "E_FName": "lisa",
   "E_LName":"King",
   "E_Place": "Rome"
  },
  {
   "E_ID": 126,
   "E_FName": "John",
   "E_LName":"Lever",
   "E_Place": "Rome"
  },
  {
   "E_ID": 127,
   "E_FName": "Lee",
   "E_LName":"Dev",
   "E_Place": "Rome"
  }
 ]}
```

This will load correctly if "dynamic data" option is disabled.